# save video files in iOS gallery using Cordova plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am trying to save a video from a URL in my iOS device using a ionic [Cordova file transfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) .

```
  var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
      var uri = "https:xyz.abc/demo.mp4";
      var fileURL = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'demoRename.mp4';

  fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL, function (entry) {
      console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("download error source " + error.source);
      console.log("download error target " + error.target);
      console.log("download error code" + error.code);
    }
  );
```

I can see the downloaded path as below using console log.

```
[Log] download complete: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB4C2F9A-9C4D-4CA6-BED0-D83B7D4CBDE1/Documents/demoRename.mp4
```

But I can not see the downloaded video file in my gallery or in photos ,Where can I find them or am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to save the video to gallery then you will able to see the downloaded video in the gallery.

please use the photo library plugin and follow the below link.

https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library

use  the below code may be it will helpful to you.

```
 //based on device type choosing the location to save the video
 if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
 var path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
 var filename = "preview.mp4";
 } else {
 var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
 var filename = "preview" + $filter('date')(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd     HH:mm:ss") + ".mp4";
 }
 //Creating directory to save video in the device

 $cordovaFile.createDir(path, "dir", true).then(function(success) {
 var targetPath = path + "dir/" + filename;
 var trustHosts = true;
 var options = {};
 //Downloading the file from URL.
 $cordovaFileTransfer.download("video URL", targetPath, options,     trustHosts).then(function(result) {
     //Once downloaded the file calling function to add the video to photo library
     if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
         function savelibrery() {
             cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveVideo(targetPath, album,     function(success) {}, function(err) {
                 if (err.startsWith('Permission')) {
                         cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.requestAuthorization(function() {
                             savelibrery();
                         }, function(err) {
                             $ionicLoading.hide();
                             $cordovaToast.show("Oops! unable to save video, please try after sometime.", "long", "center");
                             // User denied the access
                         }, // if options not provided, defaults to {read: true}.
                         {
                             read: true,
                             write: true
                         });
                 }
             });
         }
         savelibrery()
     } else {
         //add refresh media plug in for refresh the gallery for android to see the downloaded video.
         refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath);
     }
     $ionicLoading.hide();

     $cordovaToast.show("Vidoe saved successfully", "long", "center");
 }, function(error) {

     $ionicLoading.hide();
     $cordovaToast.show("Oops! unable to save video, please try after sometime.", "long", "center");
 }, function(progress) {
     $scope.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
     $cordovaToast.show("In progress", "short", "center");
 });
 }, function(error) {
 //alert(JSON.stringify(error));                
 $ionicLoading.hide();
 $cordovaToast.show("Oops! unable to save video, please try after sometime.", "long", "center");
 });
```

Comment: I am getting a refreshMedia is not defined.  Am I missing as plugin here?